# Is there accommodation at or near Tuzla airport in Bosnia?

Tags: airports, accommodation, stopovers, bosnia

In April, a friend and I will have a layover at Tuzla airport in Bosnia, arriving on 15 April at 22:55, and departing on 16 April at 06:30.

Is there any hotel/hostel/other accommodation at or near the airport, with public transportation or an airport shuttle available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Sleeping in Airport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/tuzla-airport.htm#airportHotel), there is one hotel 20 minutes from the airport which can organize airport transfers. This is the Golden Star hotel.

Searching the web, also found the Tehnograd hotel that can organize transfers (for a fee).

Answer (score 0):

[These are the accommodations near the airport, of which several offer free airport transfer](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaCyIAQGYAQe4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuoAgM&sid=58bd83ab03bb0783614b36c044f68586&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.de.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaCyIAQGYAQe4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQuoAgM%3Bsid%3D58bd83ab03bb0783614b36c044f68586%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Dubrave%20Gornje%2C%20Bosnien%20und%20Herzegovina&checkin_monthday=&checkin_month=&checkin_year=&checkout_monthday=&checkout_month=&checkout_year=&nflt=&sb_acc_types=1&room1=A&no_rooms=1&group_adults=1&group_children=0&ss_raw=dubrave%20gornje&ac_position=1&ac_langcode=de&dest_id=-79981&dest_type=city&search_pageview_id=84af055dc77a01c7&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=84af055dc77a01c7&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0). Costs EUR 15-25, so a great option for travellers in transit